Prove optimality of Huffman code
This is going to be short question. I have trouble generalizing the result of Huffman optimality for two-alphabet vocabulary. The book I'm following suggests an inductive approach, but I find it not necessary. The idea for two-alphabet vocabulary still works for the general case. As a reference, the proof is in page 126 of this book: Elements of information theory
The only thing that is troublesome is the fact that I have not proved the existence of a canonical form (definition in page 123) of optimal code (of length at least $D$) where there exists $D$ longest code-words having the same length.
This is quite simple but tricky somehow. For the case of two longest code-words for the optimal code, we simply truncate the longer to shorter one to obtain a more optimal code, which is absurd. But in the case of $D$ longest code-words, we simply cannot truncate the two longest to the $D$th longest and still obtaining a prefix code. How to approach from here?
